# Why is my cost not showing in descending order?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written the query below and it seems to work fine and return the correct number of rows. But I need the 'cost' column to be in descending order and it is NOT.

```
SELECT check_out_interval, scan_code, c.cost, SUBSTR(title, 1, 30) AS 'Title'
FROM collection c LEFT JOIN biblio b ON 
     c.book_id = b.book_id
WHERE c.cost > (SELECT AVG(cost)
                FROM collection
                WHERE check_out_interval = check_out_interval
                ORDER BY check_out_interval, cost DESC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `order by` clause in outer query .
Presently it is applied in the inner query, where it is not required.

```
SELECT check_out_interval, scan_code, c.cost, SUBSTR(title, 1, 30) AS 'Title'
FROM collection c LEFT JOIN biblio b ON 
     c.book_id = b.book_id
WHERE c.cost > (SELECT AVG(cost)
                FROM collection
                WHERE check_out_interval = check_out_interval
                ) ORDER BY check_out_interval, cost DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `order clause` in the main query instead of subquery

```
SELECT 
check_out_interval, scan_code, c.cost, SUBSTR(title, 1, 30) AS 'Title' 
FROM collection 
c LEFT JOIN biblio b ON c.book_id = b.book_id 
WHERE c.cost > 
(SELECT AVG(cost) FROM collection WHERE check_out_interval = check_out_interval)
ORDER BY check_out_interval, c.cost DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Column that you want your result to sort by belongs to Object in Outer Query so you must keep `ORDER BY` clause in outer query. 
Like this:

```
SELECT 
check_out_interval, scan_code, c.cost, SUBSTR(title, 1, 30) AS 'Title' 
FROM collection 
c LEFT JOIN biblio b ON c.book_id = b.book_id 
WHERE c.cost > 
(SELECT AVG(cost) FROM collection WHERE check_out_interval = check_out_interval)
ORDER BY check_out_interval, c.cost DESC;
```

for more Information Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)